# Get ADB to trust all computers

Tags: adb, root-access, security

Is there something I can do to make my phone trust all computers to use ADB on my phone? I have root, Resurrection Remix on Android 7.1.1, and I am open to editing some files. I will only be plugging my phone into computers that I already trust, so I'm not worried about security.

The reason I want this is because I use a different school computer every day, and I don't like the pop-up. I trust those computers and don't need the prompt.

Can somebody please get an answer? YES, I ONLY PLUG MY PHONE INTO A USB PORT I TRUST!!!

Comment: How many computers will you be plugging your device in? If it isn't that much, you can probably just accept them once individually and never ask you again.

Comment: @GiantTree The school computers. I use a different one each time. The popup is very annoying.

Comment: Do you trust *every* USB port (including charger) you plug your phone in to? Not just computers—nothing guarantees that thing that looks like a charge port actually is only charging. And of course that no one else will grab your phone, and plug it in to something you don't trust?

Comment: I don't think you can, short of copying the key stored on the PC to each and every machine you use - bu t by then, it would be quicker to do it normally. I know you DGAF about security, but one wrong move on even a scroll network can end your fun. I accidentally put VBS dunini onto the network once, requiring a full rebuild of about 70 PC's and two android tablets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Huh, It turns out you can

It turns out you can disable the verication check to bypass the ask for authorization.

On a authorised computer:

Firstly, run `adb version` and check its at least 1.0.32

Give adb root permissions, `adb root`

Then, connect and run `adb disable-verity`

Then it should be fine!

---

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37624959/4992064